# A expressão "dia a dia" tem hífen?

Tags: português-brasileiro, ortografia, hífen

A expressão "dia a dia" tem hífen nas regras atuais do português brasileiro? Quais outras palavras se encaixam na mesma situação que esta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A grafia atual é sem hífen. A regra e outras palavras estão abaixo conforme artigo do [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/$dia-a-dia-ou-dia-a-dia):

> Segundo o Acordo Ortográfico, a forma correta é dia a dia.
>
> As palavras compostas constituídas por nome + preposição + nome e que
>   não sejam termos de botânica ou zoologia, como dia a dia, fim de
>   semana, frente a frente, pé de galinha (ruga), perdem o hífen.

Comment: Alguma palavra deste tipo tem hifen em português??

Comment: pelo o q eu entendi, qnd são termos de Botânica e Zoologia, há hifen. Se não, é sem hifen

Comment: Então a resposta é que não existe. Termos de botánica e zoologia não são advérbios. Existe também os substantivos compostos que perderam os hifenes, tipo pé de cabra ou rés do chão.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo Reinaldo Passadori, do Instituto Passadori, as expressões dia a dia e dia-a-dia, antes do Novo Acordo Ortográfico, eram diferenciadas pelo uso do hífen para destacar funções diferentes, logo: quando tinha função de substantivo, ou seja, sentido de cotidiano (usava-se hífen); quando tinha função de advérbio, ou seja, sentido de diariamente (usava-se sem hífen).

Exemplos:

- O dia-a-dia do profissional do mundo corporativo é muito estressante. (substantivo)
- Convivemos com muitos conflitos dia a dia na esfera corporativa. (advérbio)

Depois do Novo Acordo Ortográfico, temos a simplificação da utilização desta locução, conforme expressa a regra:

As palavras compostas que possuem entre seus termos um elemento de ligação (representado por uma preposição, artigo ou pronome) já não mais requerem o emprego do hífen. Além da expressão em estudo (dia a dia), há ainda outras, como: pé de moleque, lua de mel, carne de sol, fim de semana, etc.

Dito isso, o atual acordo ortográfico define que não deve ser usado o hífen em locuções substantivas, adjetivas, pronominais, adverbiais, prepositivas ou conjuncionais. Logo, a forma correta de escrita da expressão é dia a dia, sem hífen.
[soportugues](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/FAQresposta.php?id=117)

Answer (score 0):

Segundo alguns estudos que fiz recentemente, antes do Acordo Ortográfico, havia as duas formas: dia a dia e dia-a-dia. Com hífen, era sinônimo de cotidiano. Exemplo: Como é o seu dia-a-dia?
Já a forma sem hífen era usada como locução adverbial com o sentido de “diariamente”. Ex.: Ele faz isso dia a dia.
Mas como o Novo Acordo Ortográfico a expressão dia-a-dia com hífen foi  extinta. Portanto, agora se escreve “dia a dia”.
Logo, na hora de escrever essa expressão, esqueça o hífen. Exemplos:

O funcionário melhora dia a dia os seus resultados.

André contou um pouco do seu dia a dia.

Dia a dia vai melhorando a saúde do paciente.

O dia a dia do profissional de vendas é bastante cansativo.

No ambiente corporativo, convivemos dia a dia com muitos conflitos.
[enter link description here](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/FAQresposta.php?id=117)